# kotlin coroutine and main handler relationship

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, anko

I'm having the following snippet

```
 verticalLayout {
        gravity = Gravity.CENTER
        button("BUTTON").onClick {
            trace("click on process")
            runBlocking {
                trace("blocking start") // #1
                delay(20000L)  #2
                trace("blocking end")  // #3
            }
            trace("click process end")
        }
    }
```

trace is a function defined as a utility function to log out messages using Log.e with current thread name

when i click the button, all code run as expected and logs show all trace functions are called in main thread
log for #3 appears after #1 within 20000L ms and no ANR Dialog shows

but strange things happened, during the 20000L ms, the button hold the **pressed state** even when i release the button right after click, then i realized the pressed state is restored when onClick method ends,

i had a raw concept that 
coroutine is a compiler magic using CPS to transform the code into a callback style function like follow

```
delay(20000L,callback = { trace("blocking end ")})
```

so i have the following questions

1. in the end who and when actually calls callback(e.g trace("blocking end")) if the answer is the main looper or something (for nodejs ,maybe the eventloop), does we should adapt the framework for coroutine and let coroutine put event to the queue ?
2. saying that coroutine is actually compiler magic, can we write the same code as the snippet above which does not trigger an ANR but keep pressed state for 20000L ?

Comment: It seems like you are making a lot of assumptions that you don't really have to make. The call to `runBlocking` creates a coroutine that runs on the same thread that it's called on, and blocks the thread on suspension points. The call to `delay` therefore just blocks the thread that the `onClick`-function is running on.

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to achieve. Current behaviour is explained by @marstran. You should not call `delay` in combination with `runBlocking` from UI thread. Either shift it to other thread by calling `launch(CommonPool)` or don't call `delay`.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `runBlocking` which is named that way because it blocks the thread it is invoked on for the duration of coroutine execution. In your particular case, you are blocking your UI thread with `runBlocking`.

You can replace `runBlocking` with `launch(UI)` to start a background coroutine on UI thread without blocking UI thread. You can learn more about various ways to work with coroutines in the [Guide to kotlinx.coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md) and in the [Guide to UI programming with coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md).